# Is it possible to use Spring Webservice Client without providing a Spring Context?

Tags: spring-ws

I need to provide a portable self sufficient java library to be used as a webservice client.
Is it possible to use Spring (WS core 2.1.0 in my case) classes without building a spring context beforehand?

Example:

```
WebServiceTemplate wst = new WebServiceTemplate(); // default SAAJ
wst.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(myUri,mySource,myResult);
```

If not, what would be needed to setup the webservice template manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can create one like that just fine. Just remember to initialize it:

```
WebServiceTemplate wst = new WebServiceTemplate(); // default SAAJ
wst.afterPropertiesSet();
wst.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(myUri,mySource,myResult);
```